# How to convert excel csv file to filled contour Google Earth Map?

Tags: kml, csv, contour, google, color

I have a csv file http://www.geocities.ws/radar/data2.csv. 
The first column is latitude.  
The second column is lonitude.  
The third column is precipitation type. 
5 represents freezing rain. 15 represents sleet. 25 represents rain. 35 represents snow. 45 represents hail.
How would I translate that into a filled contour plot like the following? 
(http://www.mathworks.com/help/examples/graphics/CreateAFilledContourPlotExample_01.png) 
I would like this on a Google **Earth** kml file. How would I edit the spacing between the contours?

Answer (score 1):

Most GIS desktop software apps have ability to plot table or csv data based on lng/lat or x/y values to generate a point event layer.  Event layers may then be exported to a GIS layer (e.g. shapefile), and then you may run a spatial analysis interpolation tool or script to create the raster surface similar to your link example.  Finally, these raster layers may be converted to a kml or kmz.  I believe QGIS app will allow you to do most of these steps either through the native tools or plug-ins.